# Thunderbird does not wrap text in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird

In 14.04, I notice that while composing Thunderbird has stopped wrapping text, and it is annoying to have to use to 'enter' to see the whole mail on screen without having to scroll horizontally!!

I don't know where to set wrap text after xx (72??) characters in Thunderbird

Answer (score 5):

There is a place it can be set although I don't know why it would have been changed on you.

From the Thunderbird Menu, choose Edit->Preferences->Advanced->General->Config Editor

In the Config Editor, enter 'wrap' as a search term

I've enclosed a screenshot of my settings for this, which work and have not been changed that I know of.

[image]

Comment: Mine shows 72 here as well. I now discover that the first line of the mail being composed wraps after 72 ch. The second line onwards goes on and on...I have not counted to how many characters...

Comment: After experimenting with the ADDON suggested above by @Tim, the firstline wrap has gone as well!

Comment: I edited this to 78 just to see if it works. No!

Comment: From editing Firefox before, if the settings in thunderbird are not default they should be bold - could you scan through the config to see if there is something changed from default?

Comment: @ Charles Green when I changed it to 78, it was bold. Said User Set or something. Since it not solve the problem, I changed it back to 72. Now it is 'default' 'integer' and no longer bold.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think toggle wrap is an option in Thunderbird. Thee is however an extension, called Toggle Word Wrap:

> Checking "Enable Word Wrap" will enable word wrapping again and set it to the standard width (which is modifiable through the "mailnews.wraplength" preference in the Config Editor, the default is 72 characters).

You can also disable it whenever you want, however I believe that is only temporary.

You can get it [from the Addons site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/toggle-word-wrap/).

Comment: @ Tim...I installed this Addon, and it shows greyed under 'options' so, I am unable to set it. See my comment below the other answer, now even the first line fails to wrap :-(.

Comment: I have now removed the extension.. now the first line wrapping that worked before is gone for good. Now auto text wrapping is not possible.

Comment: Don't know, sorry it messed it up...

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to your Thunderbird profile folder

2) Make a directory named `chrome`

3) Inside the chrome folder make a file named `userContent.css` as a plain text file (be sure to show file extensions otherwise you may end up with a userContent.css.txt)

4) Edit the file with any text editor and put the following line in it:

```
* { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

5) Restart Thunderbird

Comment: FYI - Unlike Windows, Ubuntu (and all other *nix based OS's) don't use file extensions automatically and don't have an option to show or hide them. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your wrong on the hiding part.  I have Ubuntu 16.10 and on it and previous versions, Ctrl-H turns hiding on/off on Nautilus.

Comment: This answer has been copied from here: https://superuser.com/a/709723/598527

Answer (score 1):

As Charles Green [suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/512580/411295), go to `Edit->Preferences->Advanced->General->Config Editor` and enter 'wrap' as a search term. There change `plain_text.wrap_long_lines` to `true`. This worked for me.